# Installation testing of a web based application on developed .net platform

Tags: manual-testing

Is there any checklist to do installation testing of a web based application ?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is "No."

The slightly longer answer is "The testing needed depends on the application."

The things you need to cover in installation testing will vary depending on (not a complete list):

- Which operating systems the application supports
- It being web-based, which web servers the application supports (IIS, Apache, etc...)
- Any other dependencies the application has (including and not limited to database engines, file system interfacing...)
- The degree of automated setup in the installer. One-click installers will have different testing than more manual install processes.
- The browsers and browser version the application supports